# Typescript enforce partial interface

Tags: typescript

I have an application where I receive data in JSON format. A simplified example:

```
data {
  prop1: "abc",
  prop2:  123,
  COL_A12: "mydata",
  COL_A13: "myotherdata",
}
```

Where I know upfront that the data will have several **prop1** and **prop2** property names, but **COL_A12** and **COL_A13** are generated, so they could've followed other naming (i.e **COL_A67**).

I enforced an interface like

```
interface IData {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
}
```

But I cannot specify the other property's name in the interface because I don't know the exact names, although they do follow a pattern.

Is there any way to provide a regular expression for the property name's in Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no way of setting a pattern for property names.
What you can do is:

```
interface IData {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: number;
    [name: string]: string | number;
}
```

So this is valid:

```
let data = {
    prop1: "abc",
    prop2:  123,
    COL_A12: "mydata",
    COL_A13: "myotherdata",
} as IData;

console.log(data.prop1); // ok
console.log(data.COL_A12); // error
console.log(data["COL_A12"]); // ok
```

The problem is that the indexable properties are of type `string | number` (because it can't be just `string` as the object has the `prop2` which is a `number`), so:

```
let a = data["COL_A12"]; // typeof a is 'string | number'
let b = data["COL_A12"] as string; // typeof a is 'string'
```

---

#### Edit

As you receive the data, you have no way of controlling what's in it (if I understand correctly) so this interface is just to make sense of what data you get and its structure.

If you want to then control how this data is accessed in your application then you can create a class which takes this data and exposes specific getters, for example:

```
class Data {
    private raw: IData;

    constructor(data: IData) {
        this.raw = data;
    }

    public get prop1(): string {
        return this.raw.prop1;
    }

    public get prop2(): number {
        return this.raw.prop2;
    }

    public col(num: number): string {
        return this.raw[`COL_A${ num }`] as string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still, this mechanism allows also any other property name and invalidates the idea of only allowing the parsing of the properties I myself enumerate. Thank you allthesame.

Comment: Check my revised answer